# Validity time of the URL from an NSItemProvider

Tags: swift, uikit

I’m writing a sharing extension that will accept images and perform some action with them. Within a method of my `UIViewController` subclass, I can access URLs to a particular representation of the files by writing this:

```
guard let context = self.extensionContext else {
    return
}
guard let items = context.inputItems as? [NSExtensionItem] else {
    return
}

for item in items {
    guard let attachments = item.attachments else {
        continue
    }

    for attachment in attachments {
        guard attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.jpeg") else {
            continue
        }
        attachment.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.jpeg") { (url, error) in
            if let url = url {
                // How long is this "url" valid?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the block I pass to `loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier:completionHandler:)`, I’m given the URL to a file—in this case, a JPEG. Can I assume anything about how long this URL is valid? Specifically, is it safe to write the URL itself to some shared storage area so that my app can access the pointed-to file later? Or should I assume that the URL is ephemeral and that, if I want access to the file it points at, I should make my own copy of that file within this block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `loadFileRepresentation` states:

> This method writes a copy of the file’s data to a temporary file, which the system deletes when the completion handler returns.

So `url` is valid to the closing curly brace of the completion handler.

You need to copy the file to a known location with the sandbox before you are done in the completion handler if you need access to the file beyond the completion handler.